# Derby/JavaDB vs SQLiteJDBC

Tags: java, sqlite, derby, javadb, sqlitejdbc

I found a lot of comparisions here, but not this one;
So, what is best in each one?

Comment: @Macarse a small standalone app in Java

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's a full comparison at [SQLite's site](https://web.archive.org/web/20180326214905/http://www.sqlite.org:80/cvstrac/wiki?p=SqliteVersusDerby).

SQLite is much more restricted, as it only supports a small subset of SQL92, whereas Derby (now JavaDB) has full support of SQL92 and SQL99.

Comment: Nice! Of course I would like to know if the Derby team point of view about this comparison.. but thanks anyway :)

Comment: Here's a thread in the derby user mailing lists: http://old.nabble.com/Derby-v-SQLite-td13496423.html

Comment: still not what I expected, but thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I execute a complex SQL which has more than 6000 rows 10000 times in my Websphere Server. Total net execution  times are like that:

> ```
>           Derby (In Memory)   Oracle(standard DB) SQLite (In Memory)  HSQLDb (In Memory)
>           nano sec.  second    nano sec.  second  nano sec.  second   nano sec. second
> 1. try    58000000    0,058   6149976000   6,1    1141988000   1,14   999403000    1,00
> 2. try    78560000    0,078   5268477000   5,2    1182621000   1,18   1338705000   1,34
> 3. try    58849000    0,058   5200898000   5,2    1133003000   1,13   2239527000   2,24
> 4. try    60901000    0,06    5435216000   5,4    1205442000   1,21   1370711000   1,37
> 5. try    58798000    0,058   6501929000   6,5    1186734000   1,19   1001800000   1,00
> 6. try    62928000    0,062   5913053000   5,9    1224470000   1,22   1066736000   1,07
> 7. try    71171000    0,071   5111207000   5,1    1200769000   1,20   1304524000   1,30
> 8. try    66913000    0,066   5517989000   5,5    1173495000   1,17   1299230000   1,30
> 9. try    58777000    0,058   7209555000   7,2    1179013000   1,18   1031795000   1,03
> 10. try   75299000    0,075   5356514000   5,3    1182715000   1,18   1368461000   1,37
> average   65019600    0,064   5766481400   5,7    1181025000   1,18   1302089200   1,30
> ```

I obviously compare Derby, SQLite and HSQLDB. Oracle isn't a in memory db. But I put it's result to table because to show speed difference between a in memory db and normal db.

PS: In SQLite and HSQLDB results aren't stable. So I choosed 10 stable results in 100 tries. Sometimes HSQLDB is faster than SQLite. I think theirs performance are same.